# Update a nested Array Value with Another Nested Array Data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 2 nested object array, I would like to update the first array's nested array value with the second array nested array values. I had done a brute force approach but I would like to improve my logic.

The first array is

```
    [{
        "name": "data",
        "values": [{
                "cid": 1,
                "ccount": 0
            },
            {
                "cid": 2,
                "ccount": 0
            },
            {
                "cid": 3,
                "ccount": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "data1",
        "values": [{
                "cid": 1,
                "ccount": 0
            },
            {
                "cid": 2,
                "ccount": 0
            },
            {
                "cid": 3,
                "ccount": 0
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
```

and the second array looks like

```
 [{
        "fName": "End",
        "version": 1,
        "cValues": [{
                "id": 1,
                "count": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "count": 3
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "count": 4
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "fName": "Start",
        "version": 2,
        "cValues": [{
                "id": 1,
                "count": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "count": 12
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "count": 22
            }
        ]
    }

 ]
```

I would like to update the count of nested array values inside the first array based on the id of the second nested array values.

I had done a brute force approach, my code is

```
for (let i = 0; i < (arr1.length && arr2.length); i++) {
      arr1[i].values[i].sort(this.sortByProperty("cid"));
      for (let j = 0; j < (arr1[i].values[i].length && arr2[i].cValues.length); j++) {
        if (arr1[i].values[j].cid == arr2[i].cValues[j].id) {
         arr1[i].values[j].cCount = arr2[i].cValues[j].count;

        }
      }
    }
 sortByProperty(property) {
    return function (a, b) {
      if (a[property] > b[property])
        return 1;
      else if (a[property] < b[property])
        return -1;

      return 0;
    }
  }
```

Can anyone help me to improve my code logic?

Comment: The logic looks fine to me. Doesn't seem like it's "brute force". (As long as it works.)

Comment: If your code is working, and you can fix the syntax errors, and you'd like to get a review of all of your code, you could check the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to see if your question is on topic for [codereview.se].

Comment: Ya but I want to improve the time complexity and I am new to javascript I don't know you to use map and find operators to improve my code

Comment: I would convert them to id based objects and then match them

Comment: Can Anyone has a suggestion to improve my logic